# Setup Spring @Scheduled annotation programmatically

Tags: java, spring

How can I setup programmatically the @Scheduled annotation?

For example:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 600000)
private void checkUserMostView(){...}
```

**SOLUTION**

Although the solution provided by the buddies more below it's alright, finally I have decided to implement this other aproximation.

http://rockyj.in/2011/06/29/using-spring-for-scheduling-tasks.html

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood your question. Did you mean you wanted to be able to trigger the scheduling in your program? The answer I have below doesn't do that.

Comment: The following [link](http://www.javabeat.net/task-execution-scheduling-spring/) may be helpful

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816568/how-to-create-trigger-object-programmatically

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There are a lot of components involved.

Comment: Thank you to all, but finally I have decided to use this implementation http://rockyj.in/2011/06/29/using-spring-for-scheduling-tasks.html